# How to print an output inside a box in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a task in NetLogo and I have to create a simple calculator. I have completed the given task but I need to print the output inside a box in addition to the command center. Since I'm very new to NetLogo it is difficult find the code lines.

```
let output 0
 let a Number_1
 let b Number_2
if operator = "+" [
    set output a + b
    print (word "result = " output)]
```

The above code is for add operator and I'm looking for the next line to print the result inside a box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things. (1) Create an `output` widget on your interface (like a button or plot) to receive the text. (2) Use `output-print` instead of `print` (see the NetLogo dictionary for details).